# Why does this particular Diagram in Third Order $\Phi^4$ theory not contribute?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608833/) question Moeman asked a question about third order Feynman diagrams in $\phi^4$ theory.
I am also working on this problem now on my own and encountered the diagram illustrated below, which comes from the following term: $$<0|T\phi{(x_1)}\phi{(x_2)}\phi^4(u)\phi^4(v)\phi^4(w)|0>.$$ But this diagram is not listed in the linked question. Is this diagram a vacuum bubble or is it equivalent to any drawn in the linked question? I don't see why either of these might be true. Shouldn't therefore this diagram contribute?

[image: One particular third order Feynman diagram]

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable diagram to me. The previous question’s author may have just missed it.

Comment: @Zack thanks. I guess you're right, maybe the author did forget it.